# Custom Graphics on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add a grid on each UICollectionViewCell in my UICollectionView. Here is what I tried to do:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    int width = rect.size.width;
    int height = rect.size.height;

    int i = 0;

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    UIBezierPath* drawingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    for( i = 0 ; i <= width ; i += width/3) {
        [drawingPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(i, 0)];
        [drawingPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(i, height)];
        NSLog(@"width:%d, height:%d", height, i);
    }
    for( i = 0 ; i <= height ; i += height/3) {
        [drawingPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0,i)];
        [drawingPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, i)];
    }
    [drawingPath stroke];
}
```

However, I end up with something that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The other thing is that I want to color in certain squares in the grid. Is there any simple way of doing that without creating additional subviews? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What is one cell in your image? Is each number one cell? I tried your code, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @rdelmar Each number is a cell. That's strange.

Comment: @rdelmar The way I set this up was I created a BackgroundView class with this `drawRect` method. I then set each cell's backgroundView property to an initialized copy of the BackgroundView class. Is that how you did it?

Comment: No, I just dropped your code into the .m file of my subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: I did that originally and that resulted in the same thing as my original question.